# Can someone translate what is written in this photo please?

Tags: translation, mandarin, characters, cantonese

Please i need help translating this into english. I have no idea what it says. [image: No idea what this says. Please help.]

Comment: It is not a sentence, if that's what you are thinking?

Answer (score 2):

Those are traditional characters

愛 (ài) Love

尊敬 (zūnjìng) Respect, honour, esteem

忠誠 (zhōngchéng)  Loyal, faithful